# Why is BinaryReadList faster than BinaryRead?

Tags: import, data-acquisition

I work on a package for Mathematica which reads some binary data from a file. I use `BinaryRead` to read data from the file, but it looks like `BinaryReadList` is faster if one needs to read a bunch of data. For example this

```
Table[BinaryRead[binFile, "UnsignedInteger32"], {100000}]
```

is around 4 times slower then

```
BinaryReadList[binFile, "UnsignedInteger32", 100000]
```

However, `BinaryReadList` does not maintain the position in the stream so its usage is problematic from my point of view. I would like to know if I can speed up the readout using `BinaryRead`. Or maybe I can make `BinaryReadList` to remember the position in the stream.

Comment: Why not spelunk both definitions, see what you can come up on your own ?

Comment: `BinaryReadList` is faster for a usual (for Mathematica) reason: it operates at a lower level with more data at once. While `Table` is a top-level iteration, which requires a round-trip to the main evaluator at every iteration - which is the main reason for the slow-down here. As to the stream position, I don't understand your comment: for me, both `StreamPosition` and `SetStreamPosition` work perfectly also with `BinaryReadList`.

Comment: `BinaryReadList` *does* maintain the position in the stream.  Why do you think it doesn't?  Did you `OpenRead` the file?  It's best to post a *complete* minimal example, in this case `binFile` is not defined and there's no test to show that the stream position is reset.

Comment: Concerning the stream position I meant that `BinaryReadList` does not alter the position.

Comment: @JarekMiszczak I cannot reproduce the problem you mention about the stream position.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think I know where is the problem. Let us assume that we have a `file` located in some directory `dir` and we define `fileName = dir <> file`. Leonid is right - `BinaryReadList` works with `SetStreamPosition`, but not if one uses file name.

Comment: That's why I asked if you used `OpenRead`, and why I asked for a complete minimal example.

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, I used `OpenRead`, but functions in my package were using the name of the file name, not the stream. Anyway, I think that this allows me to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Having confirmed what you say, I think that may be considered a bug (or at least a documentation bug)  that `BinaryReadList[filename]` reads from the beginning and does not change `StreamPosition` in the case where the named file is already open.  (So far as I know all other low level i/o functions can use the stream object or name interchangeably )

Comment: @Szabolcs Is there a way to stop after reading a certain amount of data using BinaryReadList? For example, how to do `Table[BinaryRead[stream,{"Real32","UnsignedInteger8"}],{50}]` in terms of binary read?

Comment: @Szabolcs Found the answer, it seems that it does support `BinaryReadList[stream,{"Real32","UnsignedInteger8"},{50}]`.